# How to use proxy in scrapy crawler?

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, scrapy, web-crawler

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scraper_api import ScraperAPIClient

class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    client = ScraperAPIClient('xyz')
    #Initilize method for taking argument from user
    def __init__(self, category=None,location=None ,**kwargs):
        #self.start_urls = [client.scrapyGet(url = 'http://example.com')]
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # python3
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[contains(@class,'on-click-container')]/a[contains(@href, '/biz/')]"), callback='parse_item', follow=True,process_request='set_proxy'),
        #for next page
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[contains(@class,"next-link")]'),process_request='set_proxy')
    )
    def set_proxy(self,request):
        pass
    
    def parse_item(self, response):
        # contains data
            yield{
                # BUSINESS INFORMATION
                    "Company Name": response.xpath('//title').extract_first(),
                   }
```

Here I don't understand how to write `set_proxy` function that send request to scraper API server. Please help about this.

Comment: `process_request` is documented in https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules . Proxy configuration here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy

Comment: I read already official documentation on this topic..but doesn't understand how it will be done... please provide any example link.. thanks